# Fill Canvas Hollow Circle With Different Colors According To Percentage(Gradient)

Tags: android, canvas, android-progressbar

I am trying to animate circle with different color combination according to the percentage which a task has been completed,but when i try to change the color of the paint,whole circle color seems to change,It would be a great favor if anyone could guide me in the right direction.
Following is the Canvas Class Draw Method

```
@Override
protected synchronized void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {             
    canvas.drawArc(mCircleBounds, 110, 320 , false, mBackgroundColorPaint);     
    int prog = getProgress();
    float scale = getMax() > 0 ? (float)prog/getMax() *320: 0;
    if(mHasShadow)
        mProgressColorPaint.setShadowLayer( 3, 0, 1, mShadowColor);

    canvas.drawArc(mCircleBounds, 110, scale , false, mProgressColorPaint);

    if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(mTitle)){
        int xPos =  (int)(getMeasuredWidth()/2 - mTitlePaint.measureText(mTitle) / 2);
        int yPos = (int) (getMeasuredHeight()/2);   

        float titleHeight = Math.abs(mTitlePaint.descent() + mTitlePaint.ascent());
        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(mSubTitle)){
            yPos += titleHeight/2;
        }
        canvas.drawText(mPercentageIndicator, xPos, yPos, mSubtitlePaint);      
    }   
    super.onDraw(canvas);
}
```

Following is the link to the style.xml

```
<style name="Widget.ProgressBar.CircularProgressBar" parent="Widget">
    <item name="hasShadow">true</item>
    <item name="strokeWidth">55</item>       
    <item name="PercentageCounter"></item>
    <item name="subtitle"></item>
</style>
```

Kindly Help me through this :( Any help would be Appreciated,or Guide me in the right direction,Thanks

Comment: right direction? you didnt define what you want to achieve

Comment: @pskink: I m trying to animated the circle with different colors as per the percentage for example when the percentage is 0-40 i want animation color for circle to be blue,for next 20% yellow and last one to be red,but i fail miserably and i end up changing the whole color instead of mixing them up,so hw can i solve this problem?

Comment: use RadialGradient or SweepGradient

Comment: okie,let me try that :)

Comment: @pskink: Thankuu So much,You Saved my Day! Thankuu SO much :D

Comment: @sabb, can you post updated code